# Fatal error in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to create a pdf table with `fpdf17` and am getting an error on the last line of this `if` statement (not the `}`)

```
if($fill || $border==1)
{
    if($fill)
        $op = ($border==1) ? 'B' : 'f';
    else
        $op = 'S';
    $s = sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F re %s ',$this->x*$k,($this->h-$this->y)*$k,$w*$k,-$h*$k,$op);
}
```

The error says: `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\myfilepath\fpdf17\fpdf.php on line 630`
I have two classes involved: my PDFTable class:

```
<?php
require('../fpdf17/fpdf.php');

class PDFTable extends FPDF
{
// Load data
function LoadData($file)
{
    // Read file lines
    $lines = file($file);
    $data = array();
    foreach($lines as $line)
        $data[] = explode(';',trim($line));
    return $data;
}

// Simple table
function BasicTable($header, $data)
{
    // Header
    foreach($header as $col)
        $this->Cell(40,7,$col,1);
    $this->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        foreach($row as $col)
            $this->Cell(40,6,$col,1);
        $this->Ln();
    }
}

// Better table
function ImprovedTable($header, $data, $widths)
{
    // Column widths
    $w = $widths;
    // Header
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
        $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C');
    $this->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],'LR');
        $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],'LR');
        $this->Cell($w[2],6,$row[1],'LR');
        $this->Cell($w[3],6,$row[1],'LR');
        $this->Cell($w[4],6,$row[1],'LR');
        $this->Ln();
    }
    // Closing line
    $this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');
}

// Colored table
function FancyTable($header, $data)
{
    // Colors, line width and bold font
    $this->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
    $this->SetTextColor(255);
    $this->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
    $this->SetFont('','B');
    // Header
    $w = array(40, 35, 40, 45);
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
        $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C',true);
    $this->Ln();
    // Color and font restoration
    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('');
    // Data
    $fill = false;
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[2],6,number_format($row[2]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[3],6,number_format($row[3]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->Ln();
        $fill = !$fill;
    }
    // Closing line
    $this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');
}
}
?>
```

and my `Deposits` class which isn't even being called so it doesn't matter.

---

Here is where I am creating everything:

```
<?php
//check if logged in
require_once('../config/db.php');
require_once('../classes/Login.php');
$login = new Login();
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == false) { $login->doLogout(); }

//Connect to your database
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

require_once('deposit_class.php');
require_once('table_class.php');
$deposit = new Deposit();
$pdf = new PDFTable();

$query = "SELECT r.departure AS depart, r.id AS reservation, u.unit_name AS unit, 
            CONCAT(g.fname, ' ', g.lname) AS guest, SUM(p.payment_amt) AS total
            FROM reservations r 
            JOIN units u ON r.unit = u.id 
            JOIN guests g ON r.guest = g.id 
            JOIN payments p ON r.id = p.reservation
            WHERE r.departure >= LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            GROUP BY r.id
            ORDER BY r.departure ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$file = 'deposits.txt';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $content = $row['depart'].';'.$row['reservation'].';'.$row['unit'].';'.$row['guest'].';'.$row['total'].'\n';
    file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->AddPage();

//send file to Table
$data = $pdf->LoadData($file);      
unlink('deposits.txt');         //unlink file

//create header
$header[] = array("Depart", "Reservation", "Unit", "Guest", "Total");

//create table
$widths[] = array(25,20,40,40,15);
$deposit_table = $pdf->ImprovedTable($header, $data, $widths);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Any idea why I am getting the error? It seems to be happening here: `$deposit_table = $pdf->ImprovedTable($header, $data, $widths);`

I am using it elsewhere just fine.

---

EDIT: I found in the `PDFTable` class it only outputs `here` once and then errors:

```
// Header
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++){
        echo "here";
        $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C');
    }
    $this->Ln();
```

Comment: *What* error, exactly?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this expression:

```
$this->x*$k,($this->h-$this->y)*$k,$w*$k,-$h*$k,$op)
```

Why is that: it depends on the values of the operands. Maybe one of them is an array, for example.

So you just issue

```
var_dump($this->x, $k, $this->h, $this->y, $w, $h);
```

immediately before the troublesome instruction, and look at the values. Or if you have a debugger available, place a breakpoint at that instruction, the one giving the error, and inspect the variables manually.

I notice that you have both `$this->h` and `$h`. Is that correct? If so, you might want to name your variables differently, to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: Look at my EDIT. I added the `$widths` array in the function `ImprovedTable`. I think it is somehow screwing with it.

Comment: Yes, but that does not solve your problem. You need to circumscribe it further, see which of those six variables is the culprit. `var_dump` lets you do that (a debugger would, too).

Comment: I changed `$widths[] = array(25,20,40,40,15);` to `$widths = array(25,20,40,40,15);` and get a totally different error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\fielpath\fpdf17\fpdf.php on line 426

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\filepath\fpdf17\fpdf.php on line 656`

Answer (score 0):

I found you must send the array a certain way into the `ImprovedTable` function. It must be defined like this: `$array = array();` instead of `$array[] = array();`

Why? I have no idea.

Comment: You want an array, and `$array = array()` means **define $array as an empty array**, while `$array[] = array()` means **add to the array $array (supposed existing and an array) a new element consisting of an empty array**.

Answer (score 0):

This is so old, but I find the answer for my own code. If we fall in the mistake to do that:

```
$w = array(40, 35, 45, 40);
```

Then

```
foreach($header as $col)
  $this->Cell($w,7,$col,1);
```

FPDF returns error (Unsupported operand types in fpdf.php on line ...). Because $w is an array. You must to pass always an int value.

Do that

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++ )
  Cell($w[$i], 15, $header[$i], 1);
```

Solved.